# How to add a child array to a parent array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have a list of objects from a table that are returned from an http post method in my angular service. I need to parse out the data so that it makes sense.

I have an array of Headers that has a title and a description. I want to add a child array to each header that has all of the rows that are affected by this description. How can I do this in javascript/angular 2?

So it would look like this

```
Header {Title, Error Description 1 }
     - Object 1 {ColumnId, Date, Column Description }
     - Object 2 {ColumnId, Date, Column Description }
Header 2 {Title, Error Description 2}
      - Object 1 {ColumnId, Date, Column Description }
     -  Object 2 {ColumnId, Date, Column Description }
```

Comment: What exactly does the starting data structure look like? Is it an array of objects that have 3 keys and the third one is an object?

Comment: I suspect `Array.reduce()` will work, but I don't know what we are starting from or going to.

Comment: Where is your data? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are not enough details in your request, but I would do the following:

```
let resultList = headerList.map(headerItem => Object.assign(headerItem, {
  descriptionList: getDescriptionList(headerItem)
}));
```

Assumptions:

- `headerList` is the initial list of Header objects;
- `descriptionList` is the name of the property where the child list
  should be present;
- `getDescriptionList(headerItem)` is the child list getter method
  based on initial Header object data, something like

It's just a fantasy and I need more details on the lists build process, but the child list generator could look like:

```
const getDescriptionList = (headerItem) => {
  return [{
      columnId: "001",
      date: new Date(),
      columnDescription: getDesc(headerItem, 1)
    }, {
      columnId: "002",
      date: new Date(),
      columnDescription: getDesc(headerItem, 2)
    }, 
    // ...
  ];
}
```

Here is another assumption:

- `getDesc(item, columnIndex)` is the column description getter method based on initial Header object data and column index

Comment: @CodeMan03 It's hard to be specific without a knowledge of your arrays build process, but I've updated my answer to provide an example. Hope it helps!